# How to hide another divs on click? only single div should be show at a time in react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have four `divs` i want to show single div only at a time.

Now div show onClick as per button matched but i want to when i click on a button only relative div should be display other divs should be hide. how can i do that?

What i tried:_

```js
 constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            firstDiv:false,
            secondDiv:false,
            thirdDiv:false,
            fourthDiv:false,
        }
    }
    
    
 render(){
        return(
            <div>
            
<ul>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({firstDiv:true})}}>First Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({secondDiv:true})}}>Second Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({thirdDiv:true})}}>Third Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({fourthDiv:true})}}>Fourth Btn</li>
</ul>
            

{
    this.state.firstDiv ?
    <div>first Div</div>
:null        
}

{
    this.state.secondDiv ?
    <div>second Div</div>
:null        
}

{
    this.state.thirdDiv ?
    <div>third Div</div>
:null        
}

{
    this.state.fourthDiv ?
    <div>fourth Div</div>
:null        
}


            </div>
)
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of four pieces of state, just have one which determines which div is showing. Also, how will users change divs if they need to click on hidden elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a variable which stores what you would like to show Set it to the div name which you would like to show on click of the li button.

```js
 constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
           showDiv: null
        }
    }
    
    
 render(){
        return(
            <div>
            
<ul>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({showDiv:'first'})}}>First Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({showDiv:'second'})}}>Second Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({showDiv:'third'})}}>Third Btn</li>
<li onClick={()=>{this.setState({showDiv:'fourth'})}}>Fourth Btn</li>
</ul>
            

{
    this.state.showDiv==='first' ?
    <div>first Div</div>
:null        
}

{
   this.state.showDiv==='second'?
    <div>second Div</div>
:null        
}

{
    this.state.showDiv==='third'?
    <div>third Div</div>
:null        
}

{
    this.state.showDiv==='fourth'?
    <div>fourth Div</div>
:null        
}


            </div>
)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @vishnu sandhireddy this is exactly what i want thanks again now its working fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. Div will be rendered based on number.

```js
// Example class component
class ReactComponent extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    visibleDiv: 0
  }
  switchVisibleDiv(divNumber) {
    this.setState({...this.state, visibleDiv: divNumber})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li onClick={()=> this.switchVisibleDiv(1)}>set div 1</li>
          <li onClick={()=> this.switchVisibleDiv(2)}>set div 2</li>
          <li onClick={()=> this.switchVisibleDiv(3)}>set div 3</li>
          <li onClick={()=> this.switchVisibleDiv(4)}>set div 4</li>
        </ul>
        {this.state.visibleDiv === 1 ? <div>Div 1</div> : ''}
        {this.state.visibleDiv === 2 ? <div>Div 2</div> : ''}
        {this.state.visibleDiv === 3 ? <div>Div 3</div> : ''}
        {this.state.visibleDiv === 4 ? <div>Div 4</div> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```