# Show or Hide on div among multiple divs React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to render a component based on the dropdown click.

Here is my code

```
const App = () => {
    const [showPlayer, setShowPlayer] = useState();

    const switchVisibleDiv = ({divNumber}) => {
        setShowPlayer({showPlayer: divNumber})
    }

    return(
        <>
            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown Menu">
                {data.map((info, index) => (
                    <Dropdown.Item key={index} onClick={() => switchVisibleDiv(index)}>Title - {data.title}</Dropdown.Item>
                ))}
            </DropdownButton>

            {data.map((video, index) => (
            (showPlayer === index ?
                <Plyr
                key={index}
                options={options}
                source={{
                    type: 'video',
                    title: 'Example title',
                    sources: [
                        {
                        `${video.video_url}`,
                        type: 'video/mp4',
                        size: 1080,
                        }
                    ]
                    }}
                />
                : null)
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

But it does not seems to be working i took the reference from an answer from here which was a class component and tried converting that into function component.

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501606/how-to-hide-another-divs-on-click-only-single-div-should-be-show-at-a-time-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You should change this `callback` function for the `DropdownButton` component.

```
const switchVisibleDiv = (divNumber) => {
    setShowPlayer(divNumber)
}
```

It will be working then, the original approach is `Class Component` format and in `Functional Component`, we don't use like that, just pass the `divNumber` as a parameter for the `setShowPlayer` setter function.

Then it will work.

Comment: Hey @Alan Zhou i tried your answer but it didn’t work the answer from Tushar works but when i click the second dropdown item to show the second plyr component it throws 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild'' error

Comment: @DesterKen, sorry, updated the code so you should remove curly braces from the parameters in the callback.

Comment: i tried changing the code it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a number and not an object :

```
    const switchVisibleDiv = (divNumber) => {
        setShowPlayer(divNumber})
    }
```

One more thing you could have done is remove the function and simply set state from here:

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown Menu">
                {data.map((info, index) => (
                    <Dropdown.Item key={index} onClick={() => setShowPlayer(index)}>Title - {data.title}</Dropdown.Item>
                ))}
            </DropdownButton>
```

PS: Use something else instead of `index` as `key`. It is not recommended.

Comment: i tried your answer but the first dropdown works as expected on click but when i click the second dropdown it throws this erroe 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild''